# How to Add New Record from Subgrid in Dynamics CRM with Easyrepro

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, subgrid, easyrepro

Does anyone know how to add a new record from subgrid in dynamics CRM with Easyrepro?

```
xrmApp.Entity.SubGrid.ClickCommand("subGridName", "button", null, null);
```

I used this line but it gives me an error saying no command of this name exists.

I just need to click the Add New button on the subgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a custom way to do it as the Easyrepro team didn't make a built-in method for this.

I would search the button from its text and click on it as shown below.

Make sure the target window is the main window

```
var xrmBrowser = client.Browser;
var win = xrmBrowser.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(xrmBrowser.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
```

Find the button, let's say the button name is 'New Message' with its text and click on it.

```
win.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='New Message']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xrmApp.Entity.ClickSubgridAddButton("subGridName");
```